# Left outer join with "and" in LINQ?

Tags: linq

How do I write the following in Linq?

```
select * from CompetitionDealer d

left outer join CompetitionResult r 
on d.ID = r.fk_CompetitionDealer and     (r.fk_CompetitionParameter is null 
or r.fk_CompetitionParameter = ID1)

where fk_Competition = ID2
```

The problem is that there is an "AND" on the join. 
If I move it to the where than the result is completely different so I can't do that.

Comment: Check this out :http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397895.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by dividing it into two questions:

First I selected the following list:

select * from CompetitionResult r
where r.fk_CompetitionParameter = ID1)

and than I crossed joined against the list above.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this:

```
var ls= (
        from d in db.CompetitionDealer
        from r in db.CompetitionResult
            .Where(a => a.fk_CompetitionDealer == d.ID 
                       && (a.fk_CompetitionParameter == null 
                       || a.fk_CompetitionParameter == ID1)).DefaultIfEmpty()
        where d.fk_Competition == ID2
        select d
    );
```

where `db` is the linq data context

Comment: Thank you for your answer but this syntax is invalid. :-(
The r is not valid within the Where.

Comment: Nope. Sorry. Invalid syntax.

Comment: @Keren : Where is the `ID1` and `ID2` coming from? Is is a local variable or do it belong to a table?